# Comparing two arrays of objects, and exclude the elements who match values into new array in php

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Here is my use case in PHP:

I have two arrays of objects.

```
$array1=array("a"=>"google","b"=>"edureka","c"=>"blue");
$array2=array("e"=>"https://www.google.com/","f"=>"https://www.edureka.co","h"=>"orange");
```

Compare both arrays here "google" and "edureka" string in both the arrays so in array3 with objects as "https://www.google.com/" and "https://www.edureka.co".

I want a result as

```
  array3= array("i"=>"https://www.google.com/","j"=>"https://www.edureka.co");
```

How to achieve it by using PHP array functions. If it is not possible with PHP how to achieve it using jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I have tried using the array_intersect()  function. But I did not get the expected solution. And in this StackOverflow I have seen this type of issues but did not get the right solution.

Comment: You can not use `array_intersect` for this, that compares items for equality - but you do not have _equal_ items here, you have keywords that you want to find somewhere _within_ the other element's content. You need to use something like `array_filter` on your second array, and inside the callback function, loop over the elements in the first, and see if any of those are _contained_ in the current 2nd array's element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```php
$array1=array("a"=>"google","b"=>"edureka","c"=>"blue");
$array2=array("e"=>"https://www.google.com/","f"=>"https://www.edureka.co","h"=>"orange");

$results = array_filter($array2, function($str) use($array1) {
  foreach($array1 as $searchString) {
    if(strpos($str, $searchString) !== false) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```